# launchBrowser doesn't work when invoking launch profile of asp.net core project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, configuration, dotnet-cli

When I run "dotnet watch run --launch-profile Watch" the project starts, but no browser launched.

**launchSettings.json**, profile **Watch**:

```
"Watch": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "executablePath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe",
  "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "https://localhost:5001/",
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001/",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

Comment: add this  "commandLineArgs": "watch run", and check

Comment: @HameedSyed I've tried that and it doesn't make any difference. I ended up executing dotnet directly instead of through a launch profile

Comment: Visual studio code is having this problem but in visual studio it runs fine.